# VBA : import csv file with utf-8 encoding

Tags: excel, vba, encoding, utf-8, import-csv

I created a script in order to import csv file. The script works but I would like import this file with utf-8 encoding.

Could someone help me with some of these problems?

This is my script:

```
Sub ImportCSV()
    Dim dialogBox As FileDialog
    Dim selectedFile As String
    Set dialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
 
    With dialogBox
        .Filters.Add "CSV", "*.CSV", 1
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
 
        If .Show = True Then
            selectedFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
        Debug.Print selectedFile
 
    End With
 
    If selectedFile <> "" Then
        Open selectedFile For Input As #1
            Dim rowNumber As Long
            Dim lineFromFile As String
            Dim lineItems As Variant
            Dim iteration As Integer
 
            rowNumber = 1
 
            Do Until EOF(1)
                Line Input #1, lineFromFile
                lineItems = Split(lineFromFile, ";")
 
                For iteration = 0 To 14
                    Range("ImportRange").Cells(rowNumber, iteration + 1) = lineItems(iteration)
                Next
 
                rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
            Loop
        Close #1
 
    End If
 
End Sub
```

I tried and the script works but the encoding is wrong, I would like import my file with utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Why don't you open the file and copy with something like `With Workbooks.Open(selectedFile).Sheets(1): Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("A:O")).Copy SomeWorksheet.Range("ImportRange").Cells(1): .Parent.Close False: End With`?

Answer (score 3):

VBA `Open` method doesn't support UTF8. `ADODB.Stream` can handle UTF8 encoding file.

```vb
Sub ReadUTFTxt()
    Dim objStream as Object, strData as String, arr
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Charset = "utf-8"
    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile ("c:\temp\test.txt")
    strData = objStream.ReadText()
    arr = Split(strData, vbCrLf)
    ' your code
    objStream.Close
    Set objStream = Nothing
End Sub
```